# How can I execute codes after $state.reload() is called in Angular JS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I think `$state.reload()` is ran asynchronously, how can I wait it to be done before executing code after it?

Like,

`$state.reload();
futureFunc();`

`$state.reload().then(futureFunc);`

does not work for me.

Comment: future is undefined

Comment: @RomanC I've updated. Thanks.

Comment: why you should wait if it async?

Comment: @RomanC Because my $state.reload(); will invalidify the execution of my futureFunc, so it has to be executed before futureFunc is called.

Comment: Create a new observable that will do the thing

Comment: @RomanC How am I suppose to do that? I am very new to JS. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You will get callback in $state.go

So, do something like this

```
$state.go('wherever', {whenever: 'whatever'}).then(function() {
  // Get in a spaceship and fly to Jupiter, or whatever your callback does.
});
```